# Select value based on user defined hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd trying to select values based on a user defined hierarchy.
This hierarchy is is not stored on the system.

example hierarchy:
General > Major > Recruit

Level Table (not necessarily in order!)

```
+-----------+------------+
| ContactID | CategoryID |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 | Recruit    |
|         1 | Major      |
|         2 | Recruit    |
|         3 | Major      |
|         3 | General    |
|         3 | Recruit    |
+-----------+------------+
```

Output:

```
+-----------+------------+
| ContactID | CategoryID |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 | Major      |
|         2 | Recruit    |
|         3 | General    |
+-----------+------------+
```

working sample approach:

```
select ContactID, 
case 
when "General" in (select CategoryID from Level l1 where l.ContactID = l1.ContactID) then "General"
when "Major" in (select CategoryID from Level l1 where l.ContactID = l1.ContactID) then "Major"
when "Recruit" in (select CategoryID from Level l1 where l.ContactID = l1.ContactID) then "Recruit"
from Level l
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? The actual data has 30 levels in the hierarchy and *many* records.

Using Microsoft SQL-Server,

Thanks

EDIT: (thanks for the help so far!)
The ideal solution would also **exclude** records that are not included in the defined hierarchy.

For example, we dont need to display user 5 as they have no valid categories, and user 4 should be listed as Recruit.

```
+-----------+------------+
| ContactID | CategoryID |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 | Recruit    |
|         1 | Major      |
|         2 | Recruit    |
|         3 | Major      |
|         3 | General    |
|         4 | Chef       |
|         4 | Matron     |
|         4 | Recruit    |
|         5 | Paratrooper|
+-----------+------------+
```

results in

```
+-----------+------------+
| ContactID | CategoryID |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 | Major      |
|         2 | Recruit    |
|         3 | General    |
|         4 | Recruit    |
+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: What in your data defines `'Recruit' < 'Major'` and `'Major' < 'General'`; apart from alphabetical order? Or is that how ranks are defined in your data (so `'General' < 'Captain'` and `Lieutenant' < 'General')?

Comment: Rank order is defined by someone's decision, it's not alphabetical and can be changed around. The use of military levels was a comparative example, the real category names are totally different.

Comment: "Rank order is defined by someone's decision, it's not alphabetical and can be changed around." How often does it changes? Where is it stored (you wrote it's not stored in the system)?

Comment: How often does it change? If you're hard coding the sort values and they can (will) change that can, and will, be a problem when that *someone* changes their mind. Because if someone *can* change their mind, they inevitably will, and they will again, and again and again...

Comment: It could change month to month. @ZoharPeled 's suggestion of using a cte to store the order looks like a great idea. That is easily modifiable. Testing now.

Comment: Then why not store it in a proper table instead of a cte? that way, you don't need to change the code at all, only the data....

Comment: yes, good idea. thanks. I'll look to create a category order table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an easier way, using [`top 1 with ties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [`row_number`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ContactID, CategoryID
FROM TableName
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
    PARTITION BY ContactID 
    ORDER BY CASE CategoryID 
        WHEN 'General' THEN 1
        WHEN 'Major' THEN 2
        WHEN 'Recruit' THEN 3
        ELSE
    END
    )
```

However, since the actual data has 30 levels in the hierarchy - you don't want to manually write a `when` clause for each one.
Instead, use a common table expression to pair each level of hierarchy with a number and then join the table to this cte:

```
WITH CTESort AS
(
    SELECT Category, Sort
    FROM (VALUES
          ('General', 1), 
          ('Major', 2),
          ('Recruit', 3) 
          -- and so on...
     )V(Category, Sort)
)

SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ContactID, CategoryID
FROM TableName 
JOIN CTESort 
    ON TableName.CategoryID = CTESort.Category
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ContactID ORDER BY CTESort.Sort)
```

Comment: thanks for this! Imagine a row for ContactID 4 with CategoryCode "Chef" that does not list on the hierarchy. Is there any way to exclude listing these rows?

Comment: All you have to do in this case is to not include it in the cte. Then It will automatically be excluded by the join.

Answer (score 0):

See below:

```
select 'General' < 'Major';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)

select 'Major' < 'Recruit';
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```

So `'General' < 'Major' < 'Recruit'`, so the easiest way of your SQL:

```
select contractid,min(cateoryid) from level group by contractid order by contractid;
 contractid |   min   
------------+---------
          1 | Major
          2 | Recruit
          3 | General
(3 rows)
```